# PHP: file_get_contents return wrong data

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I use below code :

```
$contextOption = array( "ssl" => array( "verify_peer" => false,
                                        "verify_peer_name" => false,
                                        "allow_self_signed" => true),
                        "http" => array("method" => "GET",
                                        "header" => "Accept-language: en\r\n"."Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"."User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:10\r\n"));

echo $data = file_get_contents('https://www.---.com/', false, stream_context_create($contextOption));
```

If I go to `https://www.---.com/` by browser, i see below data :

> a b c d

If I get `https://www.---.com/` data by `file_get_contents` i get below data :

> x z a b c d p

How ?